# Lag occurring when scrolling RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager and multiple item types (with different heights)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have implemented a `RecyclerView` using the `GridLayoutManager` and an `adpter`, containing multiple item types with different `viewholders` of different heights.

Unfortunately, the `RecyclerView` is lagging when scrolling it. I have observed this behaviour:

- On a specific low-end device (tablet), which is in a very poor condition and really slow in general, I could see a lot of lagging when I am scrolling up and down.
- On a high-end device (Samsung Galaxy S8), I see a lag on the first swipe (scroll) from the top consistently (no exceptions)

I think the different heights are the cause of this problem and I have tried a lot of different approaches. Among these are:

- setting the height of each item manually (so no wrap_content for heights!)
- Setting setHasStableIds(true) and implementing this in the adapter:

  > override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
  >       return position.toLong() }
- During nothing in `onBindViewHolder` and only relying on static content in the viewholders, defined in the xml layouts
- Removing everthing related to drawables, other graphics and fonts in the xml layouts. So only text and basic layouts like `LinearLayout` (etc.) was left.
- A lot of other minor adjustments..

I will try and give you the relevant parts of my code.

**So first, here is the xml of my screen with the recyclerview:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/customersRecyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clipToPadding="false">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</FrameLayout>
```

**And here is the code for creating the adapter:**

```
 var columns = if (isBigScreen && isLandscape) 6
        else if (isBigScreen) 5
        else if (isLandscape) 4
        else 3

 val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, columns, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        mCustomersRecyclerview?.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
        mCustomersAdapter = CustomersAdapter(customersListItems, gridLayoutManager, columns)
        mCustomersRecyclerview?.adapter = mCustomersAdapter
```

**And the adapter constructor:**

```
constructor(items: ArrayList<ListItem> = ArrayList(), layoutManager: GridLayoutManager, spanSize: Int) {
        mItems = items
        mSpanSize = spanSize
        mLayoutManager = layoutManager

        setHasStableIds(true)

        mLayoutManager.spanSizeLookup = object : GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            override fun getSpanSize(position: Int): Int {
                when (getItemViewType(position)) {
                    ItemType.HEADLINE_PRIMARY.index,
                    ItemType.HEADLINE_SECONDARY.index -> {
                        return spanSize
                    }
                }
                return 1
            }
        }
    }
```

**And an example of a headline viewholder, which uses span to cover the width fully in the list:**

Part of the onCreateViewHolder(...)

```
 when (viewType) {
            ItemType.HEADLINE_PRIMARY.index -> {
                layoutView = prepareViewHolder(parent, R.layout.customers_list_item_headline_primary, false)
                if (layoutView != null) {
                    viewholder = HeadlinePrimaryViewHolder(layoutView)
                }
            }
```

And onBindViewHolder(...)

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = mItems.get(position)
        if (holder is HeadlinePrimaryViewHolder && item is HeadlinePrimaryListItem) {
            holder.bind(item)
```

And the viewholder itself

```
class HeadlinePrimaryViewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private var mCustomersPrimaryHeadline:  MTTextView?     = null

    constructor(view: View?) : super(view) {
        mCustomersPrimaryHeadline   = view as MTTextView
    }

    fun bind(itemPrimary: HeadlinePrimaryListItem) {
        var headline:   String      = itemPrimary.headline
        mCustomersPrimaryHeadline?.setText(headline)
    }
}
```

(The XML of this viewholder is a simple textview and nothing else)

**It is scrolling smoothly when..**

The other viewholders besides the headlines, uses only 1 column (1 span) and looks different and has different heights as mentioned before.

The only thing that had a positive effect on the performance was using the same items/views, or at least items with the same height for the entire list. Both with and without setting `setHasFixedSize(true)`. It does not matter which of my item types I use, as long as they have the same height all the way down.

But that is not an option in my case, as I need items to have different heights for my customized items.

Comment: how you solved your problem.